# How to process mutliple xml lines of code, that are in one file with VBscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

So basically my xml file, has multiple line of xml code, i.e,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Stuff>... </stuff>
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Stuff>... </stuff>
   ...
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Stuff>... </stuff>
```

And what I want to do is change my vbscript that can run on one of these lines of code to run on them all, how would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I am changing the value of a node, and I change it uniformly amongst all of the lines of code.

Comment: Wow, you're going to need to include much more detail. Show the important parts of your VB code and tell a bit more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's a simple code.... Create an object load, Get node, Change the value. How is that supposed to help, this code works for 1 line, I want to know if there is a way to load each line to a different object. Or are they all in the same object in when I load this

Comment: You're basically saying "I have a tool in my toolbox that fits some fasteners, but not all fasteners...why not?" How are we supposed to answer that without details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is to access the file. As VBScript/FileSystemObject doesn't support read/write in UTF-8, you'll probably have to use an ADODB.Stream. If each line contains a wellformed/valid XML document - `<Stuff> ... </stuff>` is just a typo - you must use .LoadXml to feed the string/line to the Msxml2.DOMDocument. Then you probably can apply your 'change the node' code.

ADDED:

Proof of Concept code to show the approach:

```
  Dim sIFSpec : sIFSpec = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\01.xml")
  Dim sOFSpec : sOFSpec = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\01-1.xml")
  Dim oXD     : Set oXD = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  Dim sXPath  : sXPath  = "/stuff/name"
  Dim aLines  : aLines = Split(readAllFromFileUTF8(sIFSpec), vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo Join(aLines, vbCrLf)
  Dim nLine, sLine, ndFnd
  For nLine = 0 To UBound(aLines)
      sLine = aLines(nLine)
      If "" <> sLine Then
         oXD.LoadXml sLine
         Set ndFnd = oXD.selectSingleNode( sXPath )
         If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
            WScript.Echo "|", sXPath, "| not found"
         Else
            WScript.Echo "found   |" & ndFnd.text & "|"
            ndFnd.text = "Ekkehard Hörner"
            aLines(nLine) = Replace(oXD.xml, vbCrLf, "")
         End If
      End If
  Next
  writeAllToFileUTF8 sOFSpec, Join(aLines, vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo Join(aLines, vbCrLf)
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <stuff><num>1</num><name>Hörner</name></stuff>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <stuff><num>2</num><name>Hörner</name></stuff>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <stuff><num>3</num><name>Hörner</name></stuff>

found   |Hörner|
found   |Hörner|
found   |Hörner|

<?xml version="1.0"?><stuff><num>1</num><name>Ekkehard Hörner</name></stuff>
<?xml version="1.0"?><stuff><num>2</num><name>Ekkehard Hörner</name></stuff>
<?xml version="1.0"?><stuff><num>3</num><name>Ekkehard Hörner</name></stuff>
```

Function `readAllFromFileUTF8` and Sub `writeAllToFileUTF8` are left as exercise.

Comment: And I run a for loop, with the amount of lines, because .LoadXML takes only one line right?

Comment: So I was using a Microsoft.XMLDOM object, and I get that I need to use Msxml2.DOMDocument for loadXML. But now there is an error happening, my code looks like Set xmlDoc = CreatObject ("Msxml2.Document") xmlDoc.LoadXML "c:\location\file.xml" so I'm guessing Load XML "strips" the first line but that is not what is happening @Ekkehard.Horner